# How to use nginx as a proxy with Express and docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, docker-compose

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with my Express Server (Node.js) configuration. I have a docker-compose setup with a couple of apps (Rails, Postrges, Express and Nginx):

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  app:
    image: app-image
    volumes:
      - ./public:/usr/src/app/public
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: production
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    expose:
      - "3000"
  ui:
    image: ui-image
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
  proxy:
    build:
      context:  ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - app
      - ui
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream app {
        server app:3000;
    }

    upstream ui {
        server ui:4000;
        }


    server {
        listen 3000;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://app;
        }
    }

    server {
    listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ui;
        }

    }
}
```

server.ts:

```
// Express server
const app = express();
[...]
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('listening at 4000');
});
```

Let's say that my public IP is 188.222.22.22.
I can reach my Rails app at 188.222.22.22:3000 (using nginx as a proxy), I can reach my UI app at 188.222.22.22:4000 (without nginx) but I can not get UI at 188.222.22.22. I was trying with several configs and nothing works.

188.222.22.22 gives me 502 Bad Gateway, this is what I found in logs:

`1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`

Thanks!

Comment: If you restart nginx `docker-compose restart proxy` -- after you've confirmed you can reach the ui container directly -- does that change anything? You could also add (or change `links` as it's not really necessary unless you change the alias name)  `depends_on: -app -ui` to the proxy config.

Comment: I've found (indirectly) a reason: express server is rejecting all requests if they come to a different port than it's listening - I believe that properly headers setup is necessary. If I expose 80 for express everything works fine, all requests pass through the proxy

Comment: That doesn't sound quite right if the idea is to route it through the proxy. Did you try starting express by binding to host `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I did. I was trying with 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and empty host argument.